# 2 containers with background images and content

Tags: css, image, containers

I've been messing around with this code for a while, trying to learn CSS. I've tried a lot and not making much progress... Ultimately I want to have 2 containers each with their own background image and then I want to be able to upload content in these individual containers (youtube videos, text, etc).

The first container is where I want it to be, with the image I want, but the image is not acting as a background image, as I cant add any content to it. The second container would be to the right of this.

This is the code for the container I tried to make.

Website URL: http://fidditreviews.com/?page_id=6

```css
#container .image-container {
    width:350px;
    padding:0px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add an image with a  tag inside a div, the image will be on top of the content.

If you want the image to be on the background, you have to put it on your css:

```
background-image: url(../images/example.png);
```

Then you add content to your container and will be on top of the image

As for the second container, i can't find a second container in your page.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("image-container");
[
    <div class=​"image-container">​…​</div>​
]
```

You may want to add it below this one if you want them side by side.

Then you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5844562/1385896) to place them side by side.

Comment: I tried adding background-image to the #container id and .image-container class, but it didn't work. My image is a jpg, does that matter?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem of being a jpg. Are you shure you're giving it the right path?

Comment: ya, the img path worked fine when I just uploaded it as a picture in my content area.

Comment: But now you are on css. Do you have your css file on the same directory as the html file?

Comment: Yes? I'm using Wordpress so I'm assuming it puts them on the same directory? Sorry, I'm horribly new at all of this.

Comment: That's not happening for sure. Wordpress keeps things organized in different directories. 
You have to give it the relative path from the stylesheet to your image. like ../images/image.jpg. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058167/wordpress-3-3-relative-paths-in-css) to see if it helps

Comment: Ok, so my stylesheet is in the directory: wp-content/themes/responsive/styles.css  ... and my image is in the directory /wp-content/uploads/2013/07/blue-comment-bubble.jpg ... to make a relative path I would have to do: ..../uploads/2013/07/blue-comment-bubble.jpg ?

Comment: It would be like this: `../../uploads/2013/07/blue-comment-bubble.jpg`

Comment: I did not... I ended up hiring someone on fiverr to do it. thanks again for the help.